# How to execute a php file using a php5-fpm pool socket?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I need to execute a php script from the command line, but if I call directly "php5 myfile.php", I will have some security issue (mainly the openbasedir restrictions and the user&group rights).

So I'd like to execute that php file from the same constraints as a fpm process (`/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/specific_process.conf`). This process has a sock file at `/var/run/php5-fpm-specific.sock`, which, I believe, would be constrained like in the conf file (same user&group, some php_admin_value, etc).

But I can't see how I can do that from the command line, and by giving some arguments.

I tried something like :

```
php5 --bindpath /var/run/php5-fpm-specific.sock -f /path/to/my/file.php param1 param2
```

But of course it does not work. How can I do ?

Note: The file I'm calling expects some parameters (here, `param1` and `param2`).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Aren't you mixing the purposes of the binaries? If you need to execute a CLI script, use `php` that's intended for CLI. PHP-FPM is a supervisor process for php scripts that are intended to be executed via CGI protocol. I don't know why you would try to kill a fly with a nuclear bomb if you can only open a window and let it fly out.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing the purpose yes. All I need is to be constrained to the restrictions made by the fpm process (mainly user&group, openbasedir restrictions). If I call directly `php5 myfile.php`, the file will have a different access.

Comment: That's right, it will have different access. You can't use fpm to execute scripts from CLI. php-fpm exists to process HTTP requests. Either make an HTTP request so fpm can handle it or implement whatever security you need in your CLI script.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will need the executable `cgi-fcgi` (in Debian part of the `libfcgi0ldbl` package), then you can do it by executing this command (this is one line with `\` escaping the newlines, you should be able to paste this to your shell like this):

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/file.php \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/path/to/my/file.php \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
QUERY_STRING=param1=x\&param2=y \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php5-fpm-specific.sock
```

You will then receive the output, as it would be sent to the HTTP server, so it will include the HTTP headers, for example for a script containing `<?php echo "The time is ", date("H:i:s");`:

```
Content-type: text/html

The time is 13:46:35
```

There are a couple of more parameters but these are the most essential ones (see how they map to the `$_SERVER` array, that's what's happening in the background):

- `SCRIPT_NAME` this is the script name as it is seen from the HTTP side. In my example the file could have been accessed via `http://localhost/file.php`
- `SCRIPT_FILENAME` this is the local path to the script -- it's what the HTTP server will usually determine from the URL, here you need to specify it yourself
- `QUERY_STRING` can be used if you also want to pass in something that would be after the `?` in a URL, be aware that we are in a shell, so you'd need to escape the ampersand like this: `\&`

See also:

- [FastCGI Example in the Nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample) for more parameters.
- [Directly connect to PHP-FPM](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/directly-connect-php-fpm/).
- [FastCGI Developer's Kit](https://fastcgi-archives.github.io/FastCGI_Developers_Kit_FastCGI.html#S4.2)

Comment: This is awesome! Seems exactly what I was looking for. I'll try it quickly and come back to you. Thank you.

Comment: I tried it and it works like a charm. I do have only one small question; How can I escape the query string parameter since I call it from the terminal ? A url_encode? It in the case I would have odd chars like &, \, /, etc. Thank you !

Comment: I gave you the bounty, since you helped me achieve what I was looking for :) Thank you very much!

Comment: You could use something like `\`php -r 'echo http_build_query(array("key"=>"value"), "", "\\&");'\``

Comment: I just tried it, most likely you can should drop the two last parameters `\`php -r 'echo http_build_query(array("key"=>"value"));'\``

Comment: It worked exactly as described. I used it for verifying enabled extensions, usual `php -m` wasn't giving correct result as it was not pointing to php fpm.

Comment: Hi:

I have a query on this approach. Executing a PHP file works perfectly. What if I want to execute something like Laravel or Symfony commands ? they are also executed by the php interpreter in the CLI as well.

For instance, I want to invoke something like: `php bin/console demo:cmd backup` (for Symfony).

I used a weird approach for this. created a file `demo.php` and wrote `shell_exec('php bin/console demo:cmd backup')` inside it and used your approach to execute this file on the fpm server.

Comment: How can this be done from CentOS? it seems that libfcgi0ldbl is not available?