# Run symfony console on container start

Tags: php, symfony, docker, docker-compose, docker-stack

I'm looking for a way, to execute symfonys console after a docker container is started, such as a database migration. I'm using a  [alpine php-fpm image](https://hub.docker.com/r/hermsi/alpine-fpm-php/), which has the following command at the end of its Dockerfile:

```
CMD     ["php-fpm"]
```

When i try to override this in my docker-compose file, either php-fpm won't start or the symfony console command won't run. Ideally the execution should wait a few seconds, to ensure that the database is started.

What would be a good solution for this scenario?

Comment: I guess for console commands you need `php-cli` but not `php-fpm`

Comment: yes that is what i did in my compose file: `command: php /bin/console some:command && php-fpm` - did not work

Comment: What do you mean by **yes**? `php-cli` is not part of that container you've mentioned. container name `alpine-fpm-php` clearly says that there is only php-fpm. So you need to create another container with php-cli to run together or aside of your `alpine-fpm-php` container

Comment: This images provides an php binary,  which is exceutable by cli...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238602/how-to-execute-a-php-file-using-a-php5-fpm-pool-socket